# Where are user locale settings stored?

Tags: 18.04, settings, locale

I have updated locale settings from UI in 
Settings -> Region and language -> Formats
in Ububntu 18.

I can't find where these settings are stored in the OS.

So far I checked

- `/etc/default/locale`
- `~/.profile`
- `~/.bashrc`
- `/etc/environment`

but my changes reflected nowhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user specific settings are stored in `~/.pam_environment`. If there is only one user account on the system, the settings are concurrently stored in `/etc/default/locale` too.

Comment: I have had this broken by `/etc/profile.d/01-locale-fix.sh` when I delimited my `~/.pam_environment` settings in double quotes, but following the format described in `man 5 pam_env.conf` fixed it.

Comment: @anx: Well, probably you made some mistake when editing `~/.pam_environment` manually and PAM misinterpreted your settings. But when using the UI, it should do the right thing. If you have found otherwise, I'm very interested in knowing more about your observations.

Answer (score 2):

Changes in `Settings -> Region and language -> Formats` are stored in an unordered database: `~/.config/dconf/user`

You can access and change these values through the settings you mentioned in your question, through `dconf`, or `dconf-editor`.

The setting is stored in `/system/locale/region`, using US as the example:

```
/system/locale/region
  'en_US.UTF-8'
```

Comment: Note that the `user` database is a binary file and as such cannot be directly edited by text editors like `nano` or `vi`

Comment: If your intention is to use the knowledge in a script, you can alter the value like so from CLI: `dconf write /system/locale/region "'en_US.UTF-8'"` - note the double string quotation

Comment: Well, yes and no. GNOME sets that value, but it's not used on an Ubuntu desktop. Ubuntu instead saves it in and reads from `~/.pam_environment`.

Answer (score 0):

Settings appeared to be in `~/.pam_environment` although my user is admin account.
Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Right. Please see my answer.